# Debugging locally service that accesses backend database

Tags: debugging, cloud, remote-debugging

Our cloud-deployed app is composed of (simplified):

1. A web front-end
2. Some back-end services
3. A database

When developing the front-end, I can easily debug by running the front-end locally, and redirecting its back-end calls to the actual services, since their endpoint routes are public.

However, I also want to debug back-end service code, together with the front-end. I can run back-end services locally, but they can't access the database, since the database doesn't have any publicly-accessible endpoint.

**Question:** How can I conveniently develop the service code? I can think of these options:

1. Expose the database publicly, maybe just the dev env's database. This doesn't sound like a good practice security-wise, and I haven't found a way to do it in my cloud platform (CloudFoundry).
2. Test everything using local unit- and component- tests. We do this, but can't cover everything, and certainly not the integration with the front-end.
3. Deploy my code changes to a dev environment, and test that way. This is what we do now, but:

   - It's a much slower development turn-around that running locally
   - I can't connect a debugger to the deployed app, so I must debug using logs, which again is slow
   - We have a limited number of dev environments, and this creates contention for them.
4. Somehow deploy a replica of the database locally as well, using some kind of test data.

**Tech details:** For cloud we use CloudFoundry over AWS. My back-end services are written in C# + .NET core 5. Locally, we develop them using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I managed to expose my database locally using an SSH tunnel. Specifically, by running `cf ssh [AppName] -L [local_port]:[db_hostname]:[port]`, with `[db_hostname]:[port]` taken from the app's configuration, taken by running `cf env [AppName]`.